# Why is the MSB for an int bit 31 in Java?

Tags: long-integer

I am looking at my lecture notes and I see this:

[image]

Why is the MSB for an int the 31st bit and not the 32nd bit? If an int has 4 bytes, there are 32 bits and the leftmost bit is the 32nd bit right?

The notes say

> the leftmost bit represents the sign of the integer... If the MSB is 1, the integer is negative. Note the MSB is the sign no matter what size of the integer type...For example, for an int, it is bit 31. For a long, it is bit 63. For a byte, it is bit 7. To get the two complements negative of a positive number, first invert all the bits, change the 0s to 1s and the 1s to 0s, then add 1.

Is that right?

Also I don't understand why inverting all bits and adding one gives me the negative number. Can someone explain this better?

Comment: Bit 31 is the 32nd bit

Comment: bit 0 is the first bit? That was unclear to me...

Comment: It is often not mentioned, but yes. Of course we usually count from 0, but in this case it makes even more sense: bit 0 corresponds to 2^0, bit 1 to 2^1 etc